# (Circuitikz) How to draw SP3T Switch

Tags: circuitikz

I am using Circuitikz and trying to get a SP3T switch. I was wondering if anyone knew a solution for either what the node format (`node[spdt]`) is or if there is another way.
I've already combed through the [circuitikz manual](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf) and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to add an extra contact to a spdt.

I placed it as a rotary switch.  For vertical placement, use .45 or `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/spdt/margin}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \node[spdt,name=S1] {};
  \draw ($(S1)!.59!(S1.east)$) to[short,o-] (S1.east);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

Although [John Kormylo's answer is the correct one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488500/38080), notice that starting from version 0.9.1 (to be released mid-June 2019) or shortly using the git version, you will be able to use the new `rotary switch` component:

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0,0) -- ++(1,0)
    node[rotary switch <->=3 in 45 wiper 22, anchor=in](R){}
    (R.out 1) -- ++(0.5,0)
    (R.out 2) -- ++(0.5,0)
    (R.out 3) -- ++(0.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: three channels switch]

Pull request and specific docs are at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/212

Comment: well, this is more advertisement than answer ;-), anyway, glad to hear that further development of `circuitikz` is in progress (+1)

Comment: @Zarko yes, you're right. I was just putting that here for the future reader, so that they know there is a more straightforward way...